# Not getting results from $geoNear aggregate

Tags: mongodb

Can you help me figure out why this query isn't returning results?

I imported a shape file using ogr2ogr to convert it to geoJson, then imported it to Mongo using this command:
    "mongoimport --db ht--collection facilities< f.json"
Then, I created index like this: "db.facilities.ensureIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"})"

Here's a sample document, along with the query that isn't returning anything and the index:

```
    db.epa_facilities.aggregate([
   {
    $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -74.501340, 39.944520 ] },
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    maxDistance: 3,
    query: { type: "public" },
    includeLocs: "dist.location",
    spherical: true,
    distanceMultiplier: 3959
 }
}
])
```

Here's the document (properties removed for brevity):

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("54ff20a90e46de508d1dae93"),
"type" : "Feature",
"properties" : {
 …    },
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        -74.50134, 
        39.9445200009289
    ]
}
```

}

And here's the index. I tried with both "geometry" and with "geometry.coordinates" with the same result:

```
    {
"geometry.coordinates" : "2dsphere"
```

}

Comment: you have an optional query filter { type:"public"}  - do you actually have documents that match that?  When I insert your sample document and run the aggregate changing "public" to "Feature" I get back the document just fine.

Comment: I'll put that as the answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

When you execute geoNear, in addition to the location filter, the query filter is also applied.   Your query filter is `{ type: "public" }` if none of the documents that satisfy $geoNear are of type "public" then you will get no documents as a result.